# Strava api: segment leaderboard two people with same name

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api, leaderboard, strava

I am 16, creating a website that shows all Strava's segment leaderboard, but Strava only gives you the name as "Paul M." for example. when fetching the API there was two Paul M's so there was no way to distinguish between these to people and put their individual score on my website.

Using this link you can see the API data:
https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/23430539/leaderboard?club_id=318793&page=1&per_page=100&access_token=fd1971ba756d8d479623a62cb59115a688131077

I just wondered if anybody else has had this problem?

if the link doesn't work just comment it will be because the access token has expired and I have created a function to dynamically create a new one, which I can give you

```js
const link = `https://www.strava.com/api/v3/segments/23430539/leaderboard?club_id=318793&page=1&per_page=100&access_token=fd1971ba756d8d479623a62cb59115a688131077`

fetch(link)
    .then((res) => console.log(res.json()))
    
//the data is in the console log as a JSON object //
```

Comment: I've built a tool that sums up the number of kudos/activity for analytics, but this problem makes it impossible to calculate properly when you have kudoers with the same first name and surname initial -- they get lumped together in the aggregation.

Comment: It would be nice if Strava also provided some sort of hash or id (other than the athlete id) in the response that distinguishes the athletes on leaderboards or activity kudos, but still keeps the data anonymous. It's impossible to accurately aggregate any of the data for analysis since you can't determine unique athletes. It seems there would be no harm in providing something that would distinguish them for API users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the first set of numbers unique to the persons profile and stays the same. Could this be used to identify the user as an id

**29T11:10:22Z**","start_date_local":"2020-04-29T12:10:22Z","rank":1},{"athlete_name":"Ray R.","elapsed_time":1879,"moving_time":1879,"start_date":"2020-04-

Comment: the first set of numbers is the start-date and start-date-local this wouldn't work because if someone did two activities their start-time would be different so both activities won't come under their name.                                        
This is the two duplicated rows:
{"athlete_name":"Paul M.","elapsed_time":1844,"moving_time":1844,"start_date":"2020-04-29T11:10:22Z","start_date_local":"2020-04-29T12:10:22Z","rank":1}{"athlete_name":"Paul M.","elapsed_time":2089,"moving_time":1996,"start_date":"2020-04-26T09:00:16Z","start_date_local":"2020-04-26T10:00:16Z","rank":6}

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://developers.strava.com/docs/changelog/), since January 17, 2018 athlete-specific data requires authentication.

So you can't distinguish between two athletes with same name/surname but you can calculate individual score of the authenticated user (and store it in a database for further elaboration).